# How can I use Airtable as a backend?

Tags: json, api, axios, airtable

I am trying to use Airtable as backend for a submit form in my project. However, I cannot seem to integrate the API and I don’t know the problem. I am using React and axios.

I am very new to both JS and Airtable.

Below is my error code:

Error in the browser after submiting the form:

Airtable error: {“error”:{“type”:“INVALID_REQUEST_MISSING_FIELDS”,“message”:“Could not find field “fields” in the request body”}}

Could somebody please what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Below is my code:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#bize-ulasin");
if(form) {

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
axios.post(airtable_write_endpoint, 
    {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    } ,
    {
         "fields": {
            "AdSoyad": document.getElementById("#Ad-Soyad"),
            "Email": document.getElementById("#Email"),
            "Telefon": document.getElementById("#Telefon"),
            "Konu": document.getElementById("#Konu"),
            "Mesaj": document.getElementById("#Mesaj"),
            "Ortam": "Websitesi"
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        })
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error with how you are structuring your axios call. It looks like you are actually passing `{"Content-Type": "application/json"}` as the payload in your POST call instead of the second parameter. You should be able to fix by [re-ordering the parameters in your call](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config):

```
axios.post(airtable_write_endpoint, 
    {
         "fields": {
            "AdSoyad": document.getElementById("#Ad-Soyad"),
            "Email": document.getElementById("#Email"),
            "Telefon": document.getElementById("#Telefon"),
            "Konu": document.getElementById("#Konu"),
            "Mesaj": document.getElementById("#Mesaj"),
            "Ortam": "Websitesi"
        },
    }        
    {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Airtable has a [JavaScript package](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js) which gives you programmatic access to any base within any of your Airtable worksheets. Airtable also generates the full API documentation for your bases. You can find your API when you go to: https://airtable.com/api

[image: Airtable API page]

Select a base and you'll see a fully-fledged API with examples calls and all.

It shows the full JavaScript example:

```
EXAMPLE USING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
# Shell:
$ export AIRTABLE_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY

# Node:
const base = require('airtable').base('YOUR_AIRTABLE_BASE');
EXAMPLE USING CUSTOM CONFIGURATION
var Airtable = require('airtable');
Airtable.configure({
    endpointUrl: 'https://api.airtable.com',
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
});
var base = Airtable.base('YOUR_AIRTABLE_BASE');
```

Comment: I found the api docs to be really sparse and not very helpful.

Comment: Are you using the Airtable package? From your code above, it seems that you're directly making HTTP requests via axios. I would recommend using the Airtable package since it handles a lot of the boilerplate for you.

Answer (score -1):

`"AdSoyad": document.getElementById("idname")` select related html element,no value

you can solve with `"AdSoyad": document.getElementById("Ad-Soyad").value` and without id tag(`#`),you already wrote `getElementById` that doesn't need `#`